# Although I don't want the edit box to remain focused, I'd like the blue focus boarder to stay?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

I've added an edit-text box and placed it within the xml file and although when the app loads the blue focus boarder appears. I'd like the focus boarder to stay, even when the edit text isn't focused. How can I do this?

**Current XML for edit-text:**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/MyTextbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the background of the edittext.
add this line into ur edit

```
android:background="@android:drawable/textfield_activated_holo_light"
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Resource is not public. (at 'background' with value '@android:drawable/textfield_activated_holo_light').

Comment: ops my bad. you need to copy the image file into your project drawable. then android:backgorund="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_light"

Comment: all sorted now :-) thanks for your help. 
Just incase, are you any good with working with fragments? Got a problem that's really got me stumped

Comment: Link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382496/problems-using-seekbar-from-app-drawer